# Referrals count generation does not count all referrals (Difficulty with loops)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently facing a problem with my while loop. Here is the scenario, I need to produce the total number of people in left side and right side of a pyramid separately. So, here is my code:

```
void GetLeftCount()
{
    string TOP = Session["UserID"].ToString();

    Connection.Open();
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
    CMD.Connection = Connection;
    CMD.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AssignedTo=@Referrer AND PyramidPosition=@Position";
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Referrer", TOP);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", "Left");
    SqlDataReader RDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
    while (RDR.Read())
    {
        TOP = RDR["AccountID"].ToString();

        SqlCommand CMD2 = new SqlCommand();
        CMD2.Connection = Connection;
        CMD2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AssignedTo=@Referrer";
        CMD2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Referrer", TOP);
        SqlDataReader RDR2 = CMD2.ExecuteReader();
        while(RDR2.Read())
        {
            string TOP2 = RDR2["AccountID"].ToString();

            SqlCommand CMD3 = new SqlCommand();
            CMD3.Connection = Connection;
            CMD3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AssignedTo=@Referrer";
            CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Referrer", TOP2);
            SqlDataReader RDR3 = CMD3.ExecuteReader();
            while(RDR3.Read())
            {
                LeftCount = LeftCount + 1;
            }
            LeftCount = LeftCount + 1;
        }
        LeftCount = LeftCount + 1;
    }
    Connection.Close();
}
```

My current problem now is that the counting of the referrals under the pyramid only reach a specific level/layer which is level 3. It is not counting the referrals under level 4 and so on.

What is wrong with my loop? Should I convert the while loop into a "for" loop? Because I got no idea how to do that without messing the code up.

NOTE: This is for a pyramid referrals projection, all comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Anyone Wanna help? :)

Comment: T.T anyone there wanna come and give me help? nothing wrong with my question right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try one of the following. Needless to say, in any case you need an index on the AssignedTo column.

(1) Use a recursive function that will count indirect referrals up to any depth. I'd use it with caution, though, as too many nested calls could really bottleneck the database.

```
int CountReferrers(string accountID, string position = null)
{
  int count = 0;

  // If a position argument was specified, add the filter to the query
  string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AssignedTo=@Referrer";
  if (position != null)
    cmdText += " AND PyramidPosition=@Position";

  var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, this.Connection);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Referrer", accountID);

  // If a position argument was specified, add the value to the parameter
  if (position != null)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", position);

  // Count the child referrers, without specifying position
  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read())
      count += CountReferrers(reader["AccountID"].ToString());
  }

  return count;
}

void Main()
{
  string userId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
  int referrerCount = CountReferrers(userId, "Left");
  Console.Write(referrerCount);
}
```

(2) Write a better SQL query that uses JOINs to flatten everything into a single command. You could add as many joins as you like, say up to 8, and if there are no referrals at this level, the AccountID8 column will be NULL.

```
SELECT
    a1.AccountID AS AccountID1,
    a2.AccountID AS AccountID2,
    a3.AccountID AS AccountID3
FROM
    Accounts AS a1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS a2 ON a2.AssignedTo = a1.AccountID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS a3 ON a3.AssignedTo = a2.AccountID
WHERE
    a1.AssignedTo=@Referrer AND PyramidPosition=@Position
```

(3) Design the database to support tree retrievals. For example, add a referrer path column like so (string):

```
AccountID        Referrer        ReferrerPath
1                NULL            NULL
2                1               /1/
3                2               /1/2/
4                3               /1/2/3/
5                2               /1/2/
```

And then retrieving indirect children becomes a lot simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ReferrerPath LIKE '/1/%';
```

Gives you all rows that either directly or indirectly refer to account ID 1. Of course, changing referrer now requires updating all indirect references so that the path stays up-to-date.

Comment: thanks for the highly helpful answer :) but nonetheless... this didnt work :( because for example.. when i get the two referrals of the top.. i need to get the two referrals also of the left and right of top and so on and so forth with all the little branches till infinity or something... but your comment about a recursive function :) i really loved that one :) ive been trying to learn how to use it and implement it... but unfortunately.. i fail :(  but the first answer is really close to what i need gonna have to try and experiment first :) ill mark as answer if i get the job done with this

Comment: this is really really close... i can feel it... all i gotta do is find a way to make the counter work :) and get the number of accounts/ID's under the main user :)

Comment: @Doron, and all - `Normally you can't have more than 1 reader executing at the same time on the same connection` - very untrue. Please read about [MARS mode at this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx). MARS is available for 10 years now? You can turn it on in the connection string options easily. This mode is perfectly "normal". Many applications and ORMs use it by default. Plus, old article (for s2005!) but containing [many insights on MARS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - jeez. How could I have never heard about that. I've often wrapped readers with transparent buffers in order to avoid this. Unbelievable, thank you

Comment: @GabrielValdezTimbol - I edited my response with 2 more options

Comment: it gives an error of "No overload for method 'CountReferrers' takes 1 arguments" i tried the 1st method... but unfortunately :( no luck can u help me out? :) i want to use the 1st method which is recursive because it will be the exact thing i need :) because the number of indirect referrals will be infinite or indefinite :) and about the bottlenecking of Database... it can be fixed :) i can manage that one :)

Comment: im also curious... how do i call the method? it's an int.. i tried making it a "public int" but i cant directly put it on the page @_@

Comment: i also like the third method... kinda like cheating xD haha :) if i got no choice i will use the third xD i got until friday to make this work xD

Comment: The third technique will work much, much faster and better. But I improved the 1st to include everything you need.

Comment: yay :) its almost working :) :) one last error :) "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

Comment: when i add connection.open(); it says it is not closed... even if i add connection.close(); :(

Comment: i keep searching for an answer for the connection problems.. @_@ all i try failed :(

Comment: FInally Got it :) Thanks Very Much For This Answer :) Because of you i learned how to use recursive functions :)